# Is the Co-ordination number of Cobalt always 6 in every co-ordination compound?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, coordination-compounds

For example in the following  compounds

1. CoCl<sub>3</sub>.6H<sub>2</sub>O
2. CoCl<sub>3</sub>.6NH<sub>3</sub>
3. CoCl<sub>3</sub>.5NH<sub>3</sub>
4. CoCl<sub>3</sub>.4NH<sub>3</sub>

in all of these complexes, we took the

a)oxidation state of Cobalt as +3 ( since there are 3 Cl<sup>-</sup> ions and NH<sub>3</sub> and H<sub>2</sub>O are neutral ligands )

b) Co-ordination number of Cobalt  as 6

and the answer to writing the compounds was:

1.[Co(H<sub>2</sub>O)<sub>6</sub>]Cl<sub>3</sub> or [Co(H<sub>2</sub>O)     <sub>5</sub>Cl]Cl<sub>2</sub>.H<sub>2</sub>O

2. [Co(NH<sub>3</sub>)<sub>6</sub>]Cl<sub>3</sub>
3. [Co(NH<sub>3</sub>)<sub>5</sub>Cl]Cl<sub>2</sub>
4. [Co(NH<sub>3</sub>)<sub>4</sub>Cl<sub>2</sub>]Cl

**My question is this: Why do we take the co-ordination number of Cobalt always six?**

**Can't Co take other co-ordination numbers like 4? or 5?**

So for the following compound

CoCl<sub>3</sub>.4NH<sub>3</sub>

Can't we write it as **[Co(NH<sub>3</sub>)<sub>4</sub>]Cl<sub>3</sub>** instead of

**[Co(NH<sub>3</sub>)<sub>4</sub>Cl<sub>2</sub>]Cl**

Also how to predetermine the C.N of the central metal atom just by looking at anions and ligands? (cases when no coordination sphere is marked like in my above examples)

Comment: [This link](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Inorganic_Chemistry/Modules_and_Websites_(Inorganic_Chemistry)/Coordination_Chemistry/Structure_and_Nomenclature_of_Coordination_Compounds/Coordination_Numbers_and_Geometry) includes a tetrahedral coordiation complex of cobalt, where the coordination number is 4.

Comment: So how do we pre-determine the C.N of the central metal atom ?

Comment: @TanyaGupta We need to know the structure (for example, *crystal structure*). Even then there might be issues with the determination of C.N. — that's why a concept of *fractional* coordination numbers exists.

Comment: Could you give an example that uses the concept of fractional co-ordination number for a compound?

Answer (score 2):

With *these* compounds, you have coordination number $6$, but like other transition metals cobalt can have different coordination numbers with the right ligands. In [this answer](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/177011/17175) the $\ce{CoO4^{3-}}$ ion is discussed as an example of a tetrahedral complex with the rare case of high spin despite the central ion having an oxidation state of $+5$. (The tetrahedral geometry and strongly pi-donating ligands favor the high-spin electron confuguration.) Five-coordination is seen in Co(II) complexes with pi-accepting organic ligands such as $\ce{o-(C6H4)(SCH3)(P(C6H5)2)}$ [[1]](https://doi.org/10.1021/ja00992a006).

1. Geoffrey Dyer and Devon W. Meek (1967). "Five-coordination. VI. Low-spin cobalt(II) complexes with with bidentate ligands". *J. Am. Chem. Soc.* **89**, 16, 3983–3987.
   https://doi.org/10.1021/ja00992a006